# Android studio not executing codes inside for loop

Tags: android, json

The codes inside for loop is not being executed. There is no error and crashing but it doesn't work. The path of the data is correct (because I checked it many times).I have posted the whole method to understand what I am doing and what my result should be. I simply cannot get the result from the for loop. What is wrong with my code?

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"entered post",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), status,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           if (status.equals("success")) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"entered if",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
                feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"entered array",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



               for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"entered for",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

                    item.setTitle(e.optString("name"));
                    item.setThumbnail(e.optString("image"));
                    item.setDes(e.optString("description"));
                    item.setFacts(e.optString("NutritionFacts"));
                    feedsList.add(item);


                    Log.d("name", item.getTitle());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }}


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"post execution complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}
```

My JSON data (a part of it because its really big).I'm getting till "success" but cannot get into "data".

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "product_id": "92",
        "name": "Carrot Juice",
```

Comment: data is empty. You're looping over nothing

Comment: what's the value of status? and does the Toast msg appear ?

Comment: Exactly what @TimCastelijns said.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch data from POST json data.

Comment: @TonyMathew you created an array called 'data', and you never put anything inside, so its length is 0. This is the reason why you never go into the loop. Because the conditions of the loop are never satisfied, even once

Comment: Because the data of that array is online and I'm trying to fetch data via internet.

Comment: You know that data in the array is online, The android studio don't know that. i cannot see anywhere `data.getJSONArray(YOUR_TAG)`

Comment: after the array it was an object,which I wrote after the for loop .

Comment: JSONArray data = new JSONArray(); This is an empty array. So for loop will not run

Comment: but you are looping over the null array size.. that is your code will never run which is inside the loop. you must enter some data in array to get its length or else it is null everytime

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have initialized empty JSON array and you are trying to achieve looping on empty data which will not work.
Try this:

```
JsonArray data = jsonObject.getJsonArray(NetworkKeys.arrayKey.toString);
```

Try with this you will get JSON data then your loop will work.

Comment: After the array its an object. thats why I have "JSONObject e=data.getJSONObject(i)" inside the for loop.

Comment: Can you understand this simple thing, your code is not GOING INSIDE FOR LOOP AS THERE IS NO DATA.

Comment: Before posting this,the code was 'JSONArray data=new JSONArray("data")' where "data" is the name of the array. It wasn't working. So I deleted "data" and tried and got the same result. After that I posted this here.

Comment: then I tried  'JSONArray data=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"))' still no hope.

Comment: You are trying to create a new instance for jsonArray. Try above answer it will work.

Comment: @Sam I've posted it along with the question.

Comment: @SwatiDongre I don't understand the part "networkKeys" and "arrayKey". When I try to enter it, its showing error.(I'm a beginner in android).

Comment: NetworkKeys is a class where u can maintain your "Key" to fetch value at the time of parsing JSON & array key is "Key" which you need to get value from JSON. In your JSON "data" is your arrayKey

Comment: Create Enum class name as NetworkKeys like public enum NetworkKeys { data } then use JsonArray data = jsonObject.getJsonArray(NetworkKeys.data.toString);

Comment: Yes, see previous comment in which I have provided some code it will work and let me know.

Comment: @TonyMathew, Accept the answer so that it will help others.

Comment: @TonyMathew You will get one option below the downvote icon. Please click on the area of faint tick mark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to properly initialize your json array like they told you in comments. My guess is that you should:

Edited after seeing json example:

Change your

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
```

for:

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"));
```

This depends on how your json is made, it should be different based on how you got the "status" but i hope u get the idea.

Comment: `s` was already casted to JSONObject , You cannot cast it again to other type. I assume `s` contains `JSONArray ` in field `data`.

Comment: you are right, i eddited to a better guess based on the previous bits of code, hard to know without seeing the json.

Comment: before it was 'JSONArray data=new JSONArray("data")' where "data" is the name of the array. It wasn't working.

Comment: it should be 'JSONArray data=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"))' then assuming the data array is in the same json you got the "status" from.

Comment: Could you edit your question showing an example of your json removing any private/sensible data?

Comment: @Ali0t I have added.

Comment: Assuming "s" is the whole string response containing the json it should work with 'JSONArray data=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"))'. if it still doesnt work i would try to log whats inside "s".

Comment: when I logged "s" I'm getting the whole data from the url.